# How to return an array of objects from array of arrays with array.map method?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

I use React and I have this array in Redux Persist reducer:

```
const data = [["2020-09-14","15:00","60","Info","April Tucker","Other","yes"],
["2020-09-14","2:00","50","Text","April Tucker","Other","yes"]]
```

**I want to return a new array of objects (for each array in the array) with some of the values from the data array. Example of how it should look like:**

```
let events = [{ title: data[0][3], date: data[0][0] },{ title: data[1][3], date: data[1][0]}]
```

I tried to use array.map method:

```
 let events [
    data.map((index) => ({
      title: data[index][3],
      date: data[index][0],
    })),
  ]
```

This does not work as I expected. How to do it properly?

Comment: first  data.map((index) => ({ this is wrong ,
 data.map((item,index) => ({}) the second arg is idx not the first one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function gives you each item of the array as a parameter in the callback function.

Use it like so:

```js
const data = [
  ["2020-09-14", "15:00", "60", "Info", "April Tucker", "Other", "yes"],
  ["2020-09-14", "2:00", "50", "Text", "April Tucker", "Other", "yes"]
]

let events = data.map(item => ({
  title: item[3],
  date: item[0],
}))

console.log(events)
```

Comment: Thank you, it is pretty simple but I was trying many other solutions so I was a  little bit frustrated :)

Answer (score 1):

the callback on the `map` function takes the actual array item as the first argument and the index as the second, while your function takes `index` as the first.

Also, you are putting the result of the map operation inside square brackets `[ ]`. The array produced by map will be placed as the first element in a new array, while you probably don't want that

```
let events = data.map(arr => ({
  title: arr[3],
  date: arr[0],
})
```

Answer (score 0):

With [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) and [shorthand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) it's easy as one two three

```js
const data = [["2020-09-14","15:00","60","Info","April Tucker","Other","yes"],
["2020-09-14","2:00","50","Text","April Tucker","Other","yes"]]

let events = data.map(([date,,,title]) => ({title, date}) )

console.log(events)
```